# Passing Javascript variable to Controller using AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm unable to pass a variable to my controller using the data parameter of an AJAX call.  What am I doing wrong?

**show.html.erb**

```
var parentStepID = 20;

$.ajax({
    url: "/steps/create_branch",
    type: 'GET',
    data: {parent: parentStepID}
});
```

**controller**

```
  def create_branch
    parentStepID = params[:parent]
    logger.debug("parentStepID: #{parentStepID}")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

The logger does not seem to get the parentStepID:

```
Started GET "/projects/20/steps/create_branch" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-06 11:56:44 -0500
Processing by StepsController#create_branch as HTML
  Parameters: {"project_id"=>"20"}
  Project Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "20"]]
####################################################################
parentStepID: 
  Rendered steps/create_branch.js.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 10.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

**Browser console:**

```
20 0:412
/projects/20/steps/create_branch 0:413
```

Also, I believe the AJAX request is working properly; I created a file called "create_branch.js.erb"' in my steps views folder and put in an alert that is successfully called.

Comment: Dumb question, but have you referenced your ajax library properly? (I presume you're using jQuery).  And do you see any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Please post the relevant output from the Rails log to show what params are being sent.

Comment: thanks for your comments; I added the browser console output and rails logs to my post.

Comment: Where's this `project_id` coming from